# JdbcTemplate.execute() throws exception Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, h2, jdbctemplate

I am new in Spring Boot and I want to just make a simple Spring Boot web application that displays entries from a database. I use H2 for the database. However, I found out that my web application throws exception when I attempt to create a table in the database. Here is the code that handles the database:

```
private void initDB(){
    jdbcTemplate.execute("CREATE TABLE users(" + "id SERIAL, firstName VARCHAR(255), lastName VARCHAR(255), emailAddress VARCHAR(255), dateOfBirth VARCHAR(255))");
    initialized=true;
}
```

And here is the error that it gives:

```
Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException] with root cause
```

Could you please tell me what am I doing wrong?

Thank you in advance!!!

Comment: Please show more code of the class with that method (especially the point where you create an instance of that class). If you create an instance by yourself (using the new keyword), then that is the problem. Make sure, that the class is configured as Spring bean and instantiated by Spring).

Comment: The problem was that I did have my class well configured in order the JdbcTemplate to work properly. After doing the work in the Controller class everything works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are not getting jdbctemplate object fix that issue, look on your dependency injection with proper names.

Comment: I have my jdbcTemplate declared as @Autowired JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate, if you mean that.

Comment: yes remove autowired while learning use other injections, autowired also works but you need extra configuration for that

Comment: Ok, can you give me example for some other injections appropriate for JdbcTemplate, or give me a place to read more about them?

Comment: use below website for your reference you will all answers from that tutorial.

Comment: Autowired works perfectly fine (don't use XML with Spring Boot, that's not necessary).